# How to split recursive array into two categories based on specific field and also get the parent path?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I have confusion on recursive function to split recursive array into another recursive arrays. Let say I have an item and inside it there is packaged items (or children), and the children also have an item and children, there's no limitation about the recursion level.

The problem
I need to separate the paths of package item object that has isOptional `true` and paths of isOptional `false`. The function should return 2 categorized array and the value inside the array must be recursive just like the input structure. Please check the diagram below

Here's input example

```js
const product = {
  name: "Product 1",
  packagedItems: [
    {
      id: 1,
      isOptional: false,
      item: {
        name: "1#1",
        packagedItems: [
          {
            id: 3,
            isOptional: false,
            item: {
              name: "2#1",
              packagedItems: [
                {
                  id: 5,
                  isOptional: false,
                  item: {
                    name: "3#1",
                    packagedItems: []
                  }
                },
                {
                  id: 6,
                  isOptional: true,
                  item: {
                    name: "3#2",
                    packagedItems: []
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isOptional: false,
      item: {
        name: "1#2",
        packagedItems: [
          {
            id: 4,
            isOptional: false,
            item: {
              name: "2#2",
              packagedItems: [
                {
                  id: 7,
                  isOptional: true,
                  item: {
                    name: "3#3",
                    packagedItems: []
                  }
                },
                {
                  id: 8,
                  isOptional: true,
                  item: {
                    name: "3#4",
                    packagedItems: []
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Here's the diagram
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xux6H.png)

What I've tried is only able to get parent's name but not building the same structure as the input

```js
  const getParents = (
    packagedItems: PackagedItem[],
    ancestors: (string | PackagedItem)[] = []
  ): any => {
    for (let pack of packagedItems) {
      if (pack.isOptional && !pack.item.packagedItems.length) {
        return ancestors.concat(pack);
      }
      const found = getParents(
        pack.item.packagedItems,
        ancestors.concat(pack.item.name)
      );
      if (found) {
        return found;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };

console.log(getParents(product.packagedItems));
```

only return

```
[
  "1#1",
  "2#1",
  {
    id: 6
    isOptional: true
    item: Object
  }
]
```

Expected result would be two arrays like this.

```js
const optionalTrue = [
  {
    id: 1,
    isOptional: false,
    item: {
      name: "1#1",
      packagedItems: [
        {
          id: 3,
          isOptional: false,
          item: {
            name: "2#1",
            packagedItems: [
              {
                id: 6,
                isOptional: true,
                item: {
                  name: "3#2",
                  packagedItems: []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isOptional: false,
    item: {
      name: "1#2",
      packagedItems: [
        {
          id: 4,
          isOptional: false,
          item: {
            name: "2#2",
            packagedItems: [
              {
                id: 7,
                isOptional: true,
                item: {
                  name: "3#3",
                  packagedItems: []
                }
              },
              {
                id: 8,
                isOptional: true,
                item: {
                  name: "3#4",
                  packagedItems: []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const optionalFalse = [
  {
    id: 1,
    isOptional: false,
    item: {
      name: "1#1",
      packagedItems: [
        {
          id: 3,
          isOptional: false,
          item: {
            name: "2#1",
            packagedItems: [
              {
                id: 5,
                isOptional: false,
                item: {
                  name: "3#1",
                  packagedItems: []
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: It seems `isOptional` can only be true in a **leaf** node. What if the tree is a random mix of `isOptional` true/false, and it alternates on paths? What determines the category then?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the isOptional true is only on leaf node, not possible in one of branches. That's why it can be categorized @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is going in the right direction, but the pack is a leaf, and matches the category, you should not continue with the recursive call. Also the collection into the `ancestors` array will not work well as you collect either `pack` or `name` in it.

Here is an implementation that gives the output you intended:

```js
function filterOnLeaf(item, optional) {
    return {
        ...item,
        packagedItems: item.packagedItems.map(package => {
            if (!package.item.packagedItems.length) { // Leaf
                if (package.isOptional != optional) return null;
            } else { // Internal
                package = {
                    ...package,
                    item: filterOnLeaf(package.item, optional)
                };
                if (!package.item.packagedItems.length) return null;
            }
            return package;
        }).filter(Boolean)
    };
}

const product = {name: "Product 1",packagedItems: [{id: 1,isOptional: false,item: {name: "1#1",packagedItems: [{id: 3,isOptional: false,item: {name: "2#1",packagedItems: [{id: 5,isOptional: false,item: {name: "3#1",packagedItems: []}},{id: 6,isOptional: true,item: {name: "3#2",packagedItems: []}}]}}]}},{id: 2,isOptional: false,item: {name: "1#2",packagedItems: [{id: 4,isOptional: false,item: {name: "2#2",packagedItems: [{id: 7,isOptional: true,item: {name: "3#3",packagedItems: []}},{id: 8,isOptional: true,item: {name: "3#4",packagedItems: []}}]}}]}}]};

const optionalTrue = filterOnLeaf(product, true);
const optionalFalse = filterOnLeaf(product, false);
console.log("optional is true:");
console.log(optionalTrue);
console.log("optional is false:");
console.log(optionalFalse);
```

Comment: Hey @trincot, thanks for your reply, I've tested your solution for the case above but then I tested in new structure it doesn't return the expected result. I think something related to the checker. If you have time, I provide the diagram here [new diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmax5.png)

Comment: Can you provide the input data structure in text format, so I don't have to type it all in?

Comment: Sure, here we go https://pastebin.com/wAHNN8Z9

Comment: That has the "3#1" object with `isOptional: false`, while in the drawing it is true. If I correct that, I don't see what the problem is. The output looks like expected. Can you be precise as to what would be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, I see what you meant now. I'm actually agree that your solution does the job but what I expect is for each leaf will have their own whole structure from 1#1 or 1#2. The example would be in leaf 3#5 and 4#2, they are rooted from 1#2, and the expected is to have different structure from each of them. so the result should be 
{ 1#2 > 2#3 > 3#5 } , 
{ 1#2 > 2#3 > 3#6 > 4#2 }

Comment: But that is a different question now. Your original question, the example and images, they all refer to a "combined" output. Even the image you posted in this thread does that. Why does the image then group 3#1 and 3#2 together? Is there any logic to this?

Comment: Yup @trincot, sorry to not letting you know for any possible cases earlier. I'll review my needs for the new question and will let you know If I can't solve it myself. Thanks a lot man! very appreciated!